# Sinatra - Is a sitewide param possible?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I am building a Sinatra app with haml templates and was wondering if it is possible to implement a sitewide param of some sort. The idea, in my case, would be to allow for a different `layout.haml` to be able to be selected for every route without having to duplicate/rewrite every route in the app.

For example, I was wondering if it would be possible to be able to GET `http://domain.com/route/:normal-params/?layout=layout_b`, and be able to append `?template=template_choice` to any route in the app and use the appropriate layout.

The only solution I can think of, which seems very inefficient, is to duplicate every single route to look for this parameter. I also feel like it could be achieved somehow with a [Filter](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Filters) but am unsure how such a thing could be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify which layout you want to load in your call to `haml`:

```
haml :post, :layout => params[:layout].to_sym
```

That way you can call `http://domain.com/route/foo/bar?layout=layout_b` and Sinatra will look for the appropriate layout named `layout_b` to render in.

You'll probably want to specify a default layout to render if none is provided as a URL parameter:

```
haml :post, :layout => (params[:layout] || "default").to_sym
```